# How run-time detects buffer overflow?

Tags: c, runtime, overflow, buffer

```
{
char bufBef[32];
char buf[8];
char bufAfter[32];
sprintf(buf,"AAAAAAA\0");
buf[8]='\0';
printf("%s\n",buf);
}
```

On Windows 7,  I compiled the program with Visual Studio 2008 as debug project.  3 buffers are adjacent. I find their addresses with a  debugger, as followed:

```
bufBef           0x001afa50 

buf                  0x001afa40

bufAfter          0x001afa18
```

The statement "buf[8]='\0'" writes the address out of buf. When I run the program, Operation System reported " Debug Error: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'buf' was corrupted."

Then I compiled it as a release project. It run quietly, no error report raised.

My question is how run-time detect buffer overflow?

Comment: i fixed your horrible formatting (slightly)

Comment: Exact duplicate (same user): [How run-time detects buffer overflow ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282628/how-run-time-detects-buffer-overflow) and probably also [sprintf function's buffer overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282281/sprintf-functions-buffer-overflow) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see if the effect of the [/RTCs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz%28VS.80%29.aspx) switch.

John Robbins' book [*Debugging Applications for Microsoft .NET and Microsoft Windows*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615365) talks about this in depth.

Relevant excerpt:

> Fortunately for us, Microsoft extended
>   the /RTCs switch to also do overrun
>   and underrun checking of all multibyte
>   local variables such as arrays. It
>   does this by adding four bytes to the
>   front and end of those arrays and
>   checking them at the end of the
>   function to ensure those extra bytes
>   are still set to 0xCC.

Note that this switch only works in an unoptimized build (debug build).

Comment: Yes, but this goes "before the return address".  The relevant area here is between `buf` and `bufBef`.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you don't.  You should write defensive code that does the proper checks to ensure that it never overruns a buffer.

The debug runtime adds a large number of checks to help find this sort of bug (and all sorts of other common memory-related bugs); these checks are often very expensive, so they are only included in debug builds or when running attached to a debugger.  They also can't detect every possible error, so they aren't foolproof; they are just debugging aids.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article on [Electric Fence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Fence) explains how buffer overruns are caught, and why you should not use such mechanisms in production code.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the run-time will detect overflows like that by allocating some extra space between the variables, and filling that space with a known bit pattern. After your code runs, it looks at the bit pattern in that space. Since it's outside any variable, it *should* retain the same bit pattern. If the content has changed, you wrote somewhere you shouldn't have.

Answer (score 2):

The three buffers are *not* adjacent.  The difference between the start of `buf` and the start of `bufBef` (the following item on the stack) is 16 bytes, but `buf` is only 8 bytes long.

The 8 bytes in between is presumably filled with an 8 byte "canary" value.  When the runtime detects that the canary has been changed by your wild write, it raises the error you have seen.

(Your write to `buf[8]` writes to address `0x001afa48`, which is in between `buf` and `bufBef`).

Answer (score 2):

Compiler in debug mode put additional range checks for operations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the stack structure. Usually compiler places extra guard bytes with random cookie around arrays, if the value at the end of the function doesn't match, there is an overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Well `0x001afa50 - 0x001afa40 = 0x10 = 16`, and `0x001afa40 - 0x001afa18 = 0x28 = 40`, so there's some space between the buffers for it to leave some known dummy data. If that's changed by the time the function ends, it knows you went beyond the end of the buffer. I'm just speculating -- they may have done it another way, but that seems one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

C explicitly permits you to over-run (and under-run) your buffers, at your own peril.

There is no short-n-simple way to detect at run-time (in release builds) buffer overflows.

Comment: It doesn't "explicitly permit" it.  It says it's undefined behavior. C99 §6.5.3.2/4.

Comment: "at your own peril" covers that.  The fact that it is undefined behavior MEANS you're allowed to do it.  Just that you accept the associated risks.

Comment: the standard says the opposite.  Undefined behavior occurs (§3.4.3) on "a nonportable or **erroneous** program construct or of **erroneous** data"  Please give the language that explicitly (spelled out) says programs may do this.

Comment: I cite the same language.  Compare this to a bounds-checked language, which says that over-runs will be blocked (usually by throwing an exception).  Undefined behavior means that you are free to try it.  The language DOES NOT PREVENT IT.  It may not work; no specific behavior is promised, ergo, it is at your own risk.   How can you read that as anything other than, "you're allowed to try... the results are unpredictable".  There are aspects of C that actually depend on carefully constructed overruns.  Haven't you ever declared a struct that ends with char data[1];  then allocated more space?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a language different from C. Some languages define the behavior of ever possible program, defining specific error behavior for doing things that are "wrong". C on the other hand leaves the behavior of "wrong" code **undefined**, which means it's up to the programmer to ensure that he/she never uses the language in ways that result in undefined behavior. Some implementations are debugging-oriented or have debugging modes that assist you in finding errors, which you absolutely need to fix before deploying the code in release/production use.