# sprintf cuts output string by itself

Tags: c

Here's my function:

```
char *HexCastName(UINT Address) {
    char Name[100] = "";
    UINT Offset;
    for (int i = 0; i < HardNames.size(); i++) {
        if (HardNames[i].Array == Hex.CurrentRegion.Array &&
            HardNames[i].Start <= Address &&
            HardNames[i].Start + HardNames[i].Size > Address) {
            Offset = Address - HardNames[i].Start;
            sprintf(Name, " : %s[%d]", HardNames[i].Name, Offset);
        }
    }
    return Name;
}
```

I do this:

```
char name[100];
sprintf(name, HexCastName(SELECTION_START));
```

The resulting string `name` is only 4 digits, though `HexCastName()` returns more. I tried to trace it, and it seems to pass the entire string to `sprintf()`, and somewhere inside it, it gets to `_output_l(outfile,format,NULL,arglist)` function. Inside it, the `format` variable at first contains my whole string, then after reading some variables the execution jumps from 973 to 978 in output.c, and my `format` is already truncated. I'm totally confused by that behavior... Why 4 letters? Maybe some failure with pointers and chars?

EDIT:

Here's the version that seems to work:

```
void HexCastName(char *buff, UINT size, UINT Address) {
    sprintf(buff, "");
    UINT Offset;
    for (int i = 0; i < HardNames.size(); i++) {
        if (HardNames[i].Array == Hex.CurrentRegion.Array &&
            HardNames[i].Start <= Address &&
            HardNames[i].Start + HardNames[i].Size > Address) {
            Offset = Address - HardNames[i].Start;
            _snprintf(buff, size, " : %s[%d]",HardNames[i].Name, Offset);
        }
    }
}

char *name = (char *)malloc(100);
HexCastName(name, 100, SELECTION_START);
sprintf(str, "%s: $%06X%s", area,
    Hex.AddressSelectedFirst + Hex.CurrentRegion.Offset, name);
free(name);
```

Comment: You are returning the address of an automatic-storage var - UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I the C programming language arrays have the same scoping rules as other variables. In your code `char name[100]` will be pushed to the stack but will be removed when the function returns.

```
char *HexCastName(UINT Address) {
    char Name[100] = ""; // Here `Name` gets pushed to the stack.
    UINT Offset;
    for (int i = 0; i < HardNames.size(); i++) {
        if (HardNames[i].Array == Hex.CurrentRegion.Array &&
            HardNames[i].Start <= Address &&
            HardNames[i].Start + HardNames[i].Size > Address) {
            Offset = Address - HardNames[i].Start;
            sprintf(Name, " : %s[%d]", HardNames[i].Name, Offset);
        }
    }
    return Name;
    // Here will `Name` be "deleted" as it exits scope, the pointer that is returned will point to garbage memory.
}
```

**You have 3 options:**

The first is to allocate the memory for `Name` on the heap in the function.

```
char *Name = malloc(100);
```

This is not recommended because you can easily forget to free the pointer that is returned:

```
void function()
{
    char *Name = HexCastName(0xDEADBEEF);
    free(Name); // If you forget to write this you will have a memory leak. Uugh.
}
```

**The second approach:**

You can declare `Name` static.

```
static char name[100];
```

If you don't know what `static` means that `Name` will always be in memory (like a global variable). This is quite nice because now we don't have to worry about freeing it's memory.

But this approach also has a **big flaw**. Multiple function calls will modify the same variable of `Name`. For example:

```
void function()
{
    char *Name1 = HexCastName(0xDEADBEEF);
    char *Name2 = HexCastName(0xDEAFCAEF);
    printf("Name1 = %s\n", Name1);
    printf("Name2 = %s\n", Name2);
    // Because we declared `Name` static will both pointers point to the same memory and point to the same string. Not very good.
}
```

This gets even worse because the function isn't declared to return a `const char *` but a modifiable `char *`.

**The third solution:**

The third solution is the one **I recommend**. It is to declare `HexCastName` like this:

```
// The user chooses were to write the result.
void HexCastName(char *NameOut, size_t BufSize, UINT Address) {
    char NameOut[0] = "";
    UINT Offset;
    for (int i = 0; i < HardNames.size(); i++) {
        if (HardNames[i].Array == Hex.CurrentRegion.Array &&
            HardNames[i].Start <= Address &&
            HardNames[i].Start + HardNames[i].Size > Address) {
            Offset = Address - HardNames[i].Start;
            snprintf(NameOut, " : %s[%d]", BufSize, HardNames[i].Name, Offset);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I used `snprintf` instead of the regular `sprintf`. This is because `sprintf` is vulnerable to "buffer overflows". If you want to read more about it you can check the accepted answer to this question: [sprintf function's buffer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282281/sprintf-functions-buffer-overflow)

This version gets used like this:

```
void function(void)
{
    char Name[100];
    HexCastName(Name, sizeof(Name));
}
```

Comment: +1. The third solution is another good option, but it also has its cons: after its use, `Name` cannot be freed like the first solution.

Comment: Looks like I just need to malloc in the main area, not in `HexCastName()`, so malloc and free will be really close to each other and very obvious.

Comment: @YuHao You can also call the function like this: `char *Name = malloc(100); HexCastName(Name, 100); free(Name);`. @feos Yes, that is the advantage of this version.

Comment: Edited the question again, to apply everything. Verify please.

Comment: @feos I cannot test the code as I don't have the decleration of `HardNames` and `Hex`. But I think that the code looks alright. `snprintf` might not work for you if you are using Microsofts C compiler (because `snprintf` is C99) but I haven't tried it. Try it yourself and if you find something that doesn't work with my code, write what here and I will try to help you and perhaps fix some mistakes I might have made (if neccesary).

Answer (score 3):

You are returning `Name` in the function `HexCastName`, which is a local array variable. After the function exits, it doesn't point to a valid place anymore.

Instead, use dynamic allocation:

```
char *Name = malloc(100);
```

Remember to free the memory when it's not used.

Comment: @feos When you don't need it any more.

Comment: Well, I don't need it after return I guess, but it exits right after returning. It must exist for some time to get to another function's space, but then there's no `Name` variable anymore, what to free?

Comment: @feos Store the return value into a variable like `char *foo = HexCastName(SELECTION_START);` then later `free(foo);`.

Comment: Please verify the version I posted in the question.

Comment: I would not recommend this. I explained why in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No that's not a problem of `sprintf`.

The reason is, you `Name` have its local scope and storage inside `HexCastName`, and passing the pointer outside the function is undefined behaviour.

To solve the problem, you could either use @YuHao's approach by dynamically allocating the storage, or have `Name` outside the functino `HexCastName` and pass its pointer to the function.

Answer (score 1):

`HexCastName` returns a pointer to a local variable.  The memory it's pointing to is no longer valid when `HexCastName` returns, and therefore you're passing garbage to `sprintf`.

You could make `HexCastName` allocate memory with `malloc` and return that, or you could have the caller responsible for passing in a buffer for `HexCastName` to write to.

Comment: The second solution sounds intriguing. Can you provide some examples? I tried that, and didn't figure out the correct way.